# Capture images from RTSP stream

Tags: python, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to extract frames from an RTSP camera stream stored with timestamp and date every minute, for 24 hours. How do I go about this? My code:

```
imagesFolder = "C:/Users/<user>/documents"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://username:password@cameraIP/axis-media/media.amp")
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate
count = 0

while cap.isOpened():
    frameId = cap.get(1)  # current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if (ret != True):
        break
    if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
        filename = imagesFolder + "/image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)

    cap.release()
    print ("Done!")

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait 60 seconds between frame capturing and break the loop after 24*60 cycles. Stream and save a frame every minute. The one minute time delta is accurate up to 0.2 seconds for 5Hz video. Use separate timer for measuring 24 hours.

```
import cv2
import time
from datetime import datetime
import getpass

imagesFolder = "C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/documents"
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://username:password@cameraIP/axis-media/media.amp")

# Use public RTSP Streaming for testing:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov")

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test2.mp4")
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate

cur_time = time.time()  # Get current time

# start_time_24h measures 24 hours
start_time_24h = cur_time

# start_time_1min measures 1 minute
start_time_1min = cur_time - 59  # Subtract 59 seconds for start grabbing first frame after one second (instead of waiting a minute for the first frame).

while cap.isOpened():
    frameId = cap.get(1)  # current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if (ret != True):
        break

    cur_time = time.time()  # Get current time
    elapsed_time_1min = cur_time - start_time_1min  # Time elapsed from previous image saving.

    # If 60 seconds were passed, reset timer, and store image.
    if elapsed_time_1min >= 60:
        # Reset the timer that is used for measuring 60 seconds
        start_time_1min = cur_time

        filename = imagesFolder + "/image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        #filename = "image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)

        # Show frame for testing
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    elapsed_time_24h = time.time() - start_time_24h

    #Break loop after 24*60*60 seconds
    if elapsed_time_24h > 24*60*60:
        break

    #time.sleep(60 - elapsed_time) # Sleeping is a bad idea - we need to grab all the frames.

cap.release()
print ("Done!")

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Capturing stream using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) instead of OpenCV: [Read and Write Video Frames in Python Using FFMPEG](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/). For Windows download the [latest stable 64-bit static version](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Extract and place ffmpeg.exe in same folder as Python script. Capturing using FFmpeg as sub-process and `stdout`:

```
import cv2
import time
from datetime import datetime
import getpass
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp

imagesFolder = "C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/documents"
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://username:password@cameraIP/axis-media/media.amp")

# Use public RTSP Streaming for testing:
in_stream = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(in_stream)

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test2.mp4")
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate

# Get resolution of input video
width  = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Release VideoCapture - it was used just for getting video resolution
cap.release()

#in_stream = "rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=multicast",

#Use public RTSP Streaming for testing
in_stream = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"

# http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg" # on Linux ans Mac OS (also works on Windows when ffmpeg.exe is in the path)
#FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe" # on Windows

command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i', in_stream,
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-an', '-']

# Open sub-process that gets in_stream as input and uses stdout as an output PIPE.
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

cur_time = time.time()  # Get current time

# start_time_24h measures 24 hours
start_time_24h = cur_time

# start_time_1min measures 1 minute
start_time_1min = cur_time - 30  # Subtract 30 seconds for start grabbing first frame after 30 seconds (instead of waiting a minute for the first frame).

while True:
    # read width*height*3 bytes from stdout (= 1 frame)
    raw_frame = pipe.stdout.read(width*height*3)

    if len(raw_frame) != (width*height*3):
        print('Error reading frame!!!')  # Break the loop in case of an error (too few bytes were read).
        break

    cur_time = time.time()  # Get current time
    elapsed_time_1min = cur_time - start_time_1min  # Time elapsed from previous image saving.

    # If 60 seconds were passed, reset timer, and store image.
    if elapsed_time_1min >= 60:
        # Reset the timer that is used for measuring 60 seconds
        start_time_1min = cur_time

        # Transform the byte read into a numpy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
        frame = np.fromstring(raw_frame, np.uint8)
        frame = frame.reshape((height, width, 3))

        filename = imagesFolder + "/image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        #filename = "image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)

        # Show frame for testing
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    elapsed_time_24h = time.time() - start_time_24h

    #Break loop after 24*60*60 seconds
    if elapsed_time_24h > 24*60*60:
        break

    #time.sleep(60 - elapsed_time) # Sleeping is a bad idea - we need to grab all the frames.

print ("Done!")

pipe.kill()  # Kill the sub-process after 24 hours
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rotem for your time on this challenge. I had tried on this but also received these continuous errors -
`[rtsp @ 0000000000706940] RTP: dropping old packet received too late
[rtsp @ 0000000000706940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000000000706940] RTP: missed 178 packets`

I've also tried using BlockingScheduler from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking as an alternative to schedule the work being executed, but to no avail. Regardless, I'd share the code of what I tried.

Comment: Try switching from UDP to TCP: Add `'-rtsp_transport', 'tcp',` after `FFMPEG_BIN,`. There is a change that the camera supports TCP protocol.

Comment: You mean this? 
`FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe" # on Windows`

`command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-rtsp_transport', 'tcp',
            '-i', in_stream,
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-an', '-']`  I think it does support TCP protocol because I added that code to the other chunk of code and it seem to capture the first photo from the frame but hasn't captured any other since then. lol.

Comment: I think it's the same challenge with the previous proposed solution. The first frame comes up and it picks up a snapshot from it which is then repeated on intervals instead of getting new frames and snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is photos stop saving after first 3 minutes (first 3 photos are taken in seconds but saved later during each minute). The solution is to ensure it saves every minute up to 24 hours.

```
import cv2
import time
import getpass
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp
from datetime import datetime

imagesFolder = "C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/documents"

# RTSP Streaming:
in_stream = "rtsp://username:password@cameraIP/axis-media/media.amp"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(in_stream)
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate

# Get resolution of input video
width  = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Release VideoCapture - it was used just for getting video resolution
cap.release()

in_stream = "rtsp://username:password@cameraIP/axis-media/media.amp"
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe" # on Windows

# Suspecting camera supports TCP protocol hence added: '-rtsp_transport', 'tcp'
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-rtsp_transport', 'tcp',
            '-i', in_stream,
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-an', '-']

# Open sub-process that gets in_stream as input and uses stdout as an output PIPE.
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

cur_time = time.time()  # Get current time

# start_time_24h measures 24 hours
start_time_24h = cur_time

# start_time_1min measures 1 minute
start_time_1min = cur_time - 30  # Subtract 30 seconds for start grabbing first frame after 30 seconds (instead of waiting a minute for the first frame).

while True:
    # read width*height*3 bytes from stdout (= 1 frame)
    raw_frame = pipe.stdout.read(width*height*3)

    if len(raw_frame) != (width*height*3):
        print('Error reading frame!!!')  # Break the loop in case of an error (too few bytes were read).
        break

    cur_time = time.time()  # Get current time
    elapsed_time_1min = cur_time - start_time_1min  # Time elapsed from previous image saving.

    # If 60 seconds were passed, reset timer, and store image.
    if elapsed_time_1min >= 60:
        # Reset the timer that is used for measuring 60 seconds
        start_time_1min = cur_time

        # Transform the byte read into a numpy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
        frame = np.fromstring(raw_frame, np.uint8)
        frame = frame.reshape((height, width, 3))

        filename = imagesFolder + "/image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        #filename = "image_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M-%S_%p"))  + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)

        # Show frame for testing
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    elapsed_time_24h = time.time() - start_time_24h

    #Break loop after 24*60*60 seconds
    if elapsed_time_24h > 24*60*60:
        break

    #time.sleep(60 - elapsed_time) # Sleeping is a bad idea - we need to grab all the frames.

print ("Done!")
pipe.kill()  # Kill the sub-process after 24 hours
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```